# Alternative way to get selected fields in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which is not working, even i don't know if it is possible or not, I just want to confirm or any alternative way if is there to use this query.

Wrong Query:

```
select i.shipping, ii.sub_total, 
    round( ii.sub_total * (ii.item_tax / 100) ) taxed_amount, 
    round( ii.sub_total + taxed_amount ) total, 
    round( total + i.shipping ) paid_amount 
from ci_invoices i 
join ( 
    select invoice_id, sum(item_qty_total) sub_total, item_tax 
    from ci_invoice_items group by invoice_id
    ) ii on i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id 
where i.invoice_id = '15' limit 1
```

Right Query:

```
SELECT i.shipping, ii.sub_total, 
        round( ii.sub_total * ( ii.item_tax /100 ) ) taxed_amount, 
        round( ii.sub_total + round( ii.sub_total * ( ii.item_tax /100 ) ) ) total, 
        round( round( ii.sub_total + round( ii.sub_total * ( ii.item_tax /100 ) ) ) + i.shipping ) paid_amount 
FROM ci_invoices i
JOIN (
    SELECT invoice_id, sum( item_qty_total ) sub_total, item_tax
    FROM ci_invoice_items
    GROUP BY invoice_id
    )ii ON i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id
WHERE i.invoice_id = '15'
LIMIT 1
```

As you see the difference that i can not use the `taxed_amount` and `total` during select query. Is there any alternative way to write my correct query?

Comment: You can't refer to an alias at 'the same level' in that way, so either wrap it in a subquery, or (better) just write it out longhand - as you did

Answer (score 0):

How about this -

```
select 
  i.shipping,
  sum(ii.item_qty_total) sub_total, 
  round(sum(ii.item_qty_total * ii.item_tax  / 100)) taxed_amount,
  round(sum(ii.item_qty_total * (1 + ii.item_tax  / 100))) total,
  round(sum(ii.item_qty_total * (1 + ii.item_tax  / 100)) + i.shipping) paid_amount
from ci_invoice_items ii, ci_invoices i
where i.invoice_id = ii.invoice_id 
and i.invoice_id = '15'
group by ii.invoice_id
```

The query plan in the above query looks simpler than the plan of the current correct query. Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bb57/4)